# Good video player for winform application - c#

Tags: video, c#, media-player, webcam

I want to use a player which should have below features.

1. Should play selected web cam from a drop down
2. Should have stop and pause feature
3. Can able to play multiple webcams connected to USB at a time.
4. Record video with audio.
5. Should get current frame as bitmap(should have an event to get each frame generated)

Currently I'm working with Aforge player. But it has no feature to record audio along with video. Also 'Pause' feature is not available. All other requirements are working fine with this player. Is there any player which I can achieve all the above features?

Found about DirectShow architecture. But couldn't found good samples for it in c#. Also says that it is deprecated. Please help to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for has a multimedia SDK, which I believe can help you do what you want. The SDK contains, among other things, a .NET [Capture Control](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/capture) with the following features related to your question:

- Select web cam from a drop down: The [VideoDevices
  Property](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/multimedia/mm/capturectrl-videodevices.html)
  gives you a collection of cameras and other video sources connected
  to the PC.
- Stop and pause feature: The Capture control has [a number
  of
  methods](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/multimedia/mm/capturectrl--methods.html)
  to control capturing, including StartCapture, PauseCapture,
  RunCapture and StopCapture.
- Play multiple webcams: If you have more
  than one device connected to the PC, you can create multiple
  instances of the Capture control on the same form, and select a
  different VideoDevice into each control.
- Record video with audio: You
  can specify the audio source using the [AudioDevices
  Property](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/multimedia/mm/capturectrl-audiodevices.html)
- Event to get each frame: Use the [LEAD Video Callback
  Filter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/multimedia/filters/leadvideocallbackfilter(2.0).html)
  which gives you access to every video frame that passes through the
  Control.

You can try these features using the free evaluation of LEADTOOLS Multimedia from [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=mm). There’s also free technical support through email and chat during the evaluation.